# Ionic 2 NavController unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, angular, ionic2

I'm kinda new to unit testing in Angular 2 and Ionic 2.

I am trying to test the `login()` method below

```
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  login() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
  }
}
```

With the following test

```
import { ComponentFixture, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TestUtils } from '../../test';
import { LoginPage } from './login';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';

let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginPage> = null;
let instance: any = null;

describe('Login Page', () => {

  beforeEach(async(() => TestUtils.beforeEachCompiler([LoginPage]).then(compiled => {
    fixture = compiled.fixture;
    instance = compiled.instance;
  })));

  it('changes root nav to TabsPage on login()', () => {
    spyOn(instance.navCtrl, 'setRoot');
    instance.login();
    expect(instance.navCtrl.setRoot).toHaveBeenCalledWith(TabsPage);
  });
});
```

But I get the following error

```
Error: <spyOn> : setRoot() method does not exist
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://lathonez.github.io/2017/ionic-2-unit-testing/) for set up.

I must be missing something. Is `instance.navCtrl` the right thing to be spying on?

Comment: You can debug the test in Chrome and inspect it (as you would do a running app). I can't figure it out from looking at the code. Press DEBUG in karma, follow the error in the console and add a breakpoint. Inspect instance.navCtrl and see why setRoot is missing. If you're mocking out NavController, make sure the mock has setRoot.

Comment: Hi, can we set a spy on login()? If yes then how?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in a similar way that I set a spy on `this.navCtrl.setRoot()` above. In one of your tests, do something like this: `spyOn(instance, 'login')`. If you need more help or if that doesn't work, feel free to ask a new question on SO and share your code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It ended being a typo. I was using `useValue` instead of `useClass` in the provide, so the setRoot method had to be accessed through prototype.

I had

```
{provide: NavController, useValue: NavMock}
```

Instead of

```
{provide: NavController, useClass: NavMock}
```